# Find a Number whose Sum of Its Digits Squared is a Prime Number (Pascal or C++)

Tags: c++, pascal

So Help me with this:
a "số đẹp" (it's Vietnamese) is a Number whose Sum of Its Digits Squared is a Prime Number.

example: 12 is a "số đẹp" because 1^2 + 2^2 is 5 , which is a Prime number.

So given 1 <= N <= 106 , find the N-placed "số đẹp" (with N is the user input)

example:if you type "1" , the program will display the first "số đẹp", which is 11.

if you type "2", 12 will pop up.

Pascal is best, but C++ is fine.

this is what i tried (which doesn't work)(written is Pascal):

```
program so_dep;
uses crt;
var n,i,c,b:integer;

function sumdigits(a:integer):integer;
var digits,sum:integer;
begin
 sum := 0;
 while a <> 0 do
  begin
  digits := a mod 10;
  a := a div 10;
  sum := sum + a*a;
  end;
 sumdigits := sum;
end;

function primecheck(a:integer):boolean;
var prime:boolean;
    i:integer;
    max:real;
begin
 if a = 2 then prime:=true
 else if (a <=1) or (a mod 2 = 0) then
  prime := false
 else begin
  prime := true; i := 3; max := sqrt(n);
  while i <= max do
   begin
    if n mod i = 0 then begin
     prime := false;exit
    end;
    i := i + 2;
   end;
end;
end;

begin
clrscr;
write('Nhap so N: ');readln(n);
for c := 2 to n do
begin
b := 0;
while b < n do
 if primecheck(sumdigits(c)) = true then
  begin
   i := c;
   inc(b);
  end;
end;
writeln('"So dep" thu ',n,' la ',i);
readln;
end.
```

It's supposed to work( that's what i thought) but it didn't.

press "1" and the output is 0 (should be 11)
press 2 or above and it doesnt work at all.

Comment: So I'm not all that good at Pascal but in the main part of the program, you read the input to variable n which you then use in the for-loop. Since the for-loop starts at 2 wouldn't that skip it entirely if it's less than 2?

Comment: @Alpha your while loop runs infinitely. you only increment b when your check is true. and b is in the while loop check, thus if your check is false, nothing ever happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // sqrt

using namespace std; // not recommended, but I'm lazy here.

bool checkNumber(int); // checks if number is a thingamabob
bool isPrime(int);     // checks if number is a prime

int main()
{
    // input your N
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Show the n-th number: " << flush;
    cin >> n;
    // check n validity
    if (cin.good() && n > 0 && n <= 106) {
        int idx = 0;    // which thingamabob-number are we at?
        int number = 0; // what is the current number?
        while (idx < n) { // run until we have arrived at the n-th thingamabob-number
            number++;     // check each number sequentially
            if (checkNumber(number)) {
                idx++; // number is a thingamabob, increment
            }
        }
        cout << "N-th number is: " << number << endl; // we have reached the nth thingamabob-number (loop exited), display it.
    }
    else {
        cout << "enter a number 0 < n <= 106" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool checkNumber(int number) {
    int digit = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        digit = number % 10;
        sum += digit * digit;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return isPrime(sum);
}

bool isPrime(int number) {
    // standard prime check, check modulo for every number up to sqrt number in steps of 2
    if (number == 1) { return false; } // 1 not a prime
    if (number == 2) { return true; }  // 2 is prime
    if (number % 2 == 0) { return false; }
    for (int i = 3; i <= ceil(sqrt(number)); i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;

}
```